# Could there exist (and if not: why?) non-elementary particles composed of gravitons?

Tags: gravity, particle-physics, quantum-gravity

I read about [glueballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glueball), which should be particles made purely out of gluons. This is a quite theoretical thing but its existence has at least been theorized.

Now, I don't know so much about gravitons, but I was wondering this: Could there exist particles made of gravitons? And if not: Why?

Comment: Gravitons carry a gravitational charge, so in principle they will interact with each other. However the strength of the interaction is vanishingly small.

Comment: @LewisMiller What an excellent answer.  Shame it is tucked away in a comment; could you convert it?

Comment: I've deleted my comment and posted it as an answer (also incorporating John Rennie's comment.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geon_(physics)

Answer (score 3):

Gluons could form glueballs (theoretically) because they interact in the QCD model that is part of the standard model (there are three gluon vertices, for example). QED lacks such entities because there are no three (or four) photon vertices. Since there is no theory of quantum gravity, there is no answer to your question. @JohnRennie (see above comment) suggests that if gravitons exist they will interact so it is possible in principle for a gravity glueball to exist.